# Input string was not in a correct format Error

Tags: c#

I am getting an "Input string was not in a correct format" error for the below mentioned code:

```
Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.ToString());
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know? We don't have the value of the string your parsing.

Comment: What value you are passing from the text box? does it contains decimals?

Comment: It's pretty straight-forward really, one or the other (or both) of the strings you're trying to turn into Int32 are not integers in string format, so can't be converted to Integers.

Comment: @RB at second readings yeah... Instead of being synical, I could of posted an answer :P

Comment: Next time when you get this error, it's useful to create a temporary variable and inspect that using the debugger by setting a breakpoint. Or use (auto)watches. This code would've shown the problem pretty quick: `var toConvert = TextBox2.ToString(); var testing = Convert.ToInt32(toConvert);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `TextBox2.ToString()` you need `TextBox2.Text` to be parsed as integer. You need to use the `Text` property to get the text from the `TextBox`.

So the following check would fail:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Carton_Qty_Bal) < Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.ToString())) 
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also you don't have to call `ToString` on Text property like you are doing in your code, since `Text` is already of type string.

```
TextBox1.Text.ToString()
```

*(You should look into [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) Method for safer integer parsing)*

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that your error is down to trying to parse

`Textbox.ToString()`

Try and use `TextBox.Text` instead otherwise you are parsing the string which represents the textbox object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Carton_Qty_Bal) < Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.ToString()))
```

does not use the `Text` property of the TextBox.

You are using `TextBox2.ToString()` which returns the string representation of the TextBox type. Use the `Text` property and change the code to `TextBox2.Text`.

But beware: You should check the value of the `TextBox.Text` property to ensure a valid numeric input.